# TCP Retransmission even if packet ack has been received

Tags: sockets, tcp, rabbitmq, mqtt, lwip

I am facing a strange behaviour of the RabbitMQ server (under ubuntu server 14.04.3 LTS).

The client is a MQTT implementation based on lwip v1.3.2 on a tiny MCU (Cortex-M3). When my client connects the server using its IPv4 address, it works and the client-server TCP socket has correct [PSH+ACK], [ACK] sequence.

But when the client connects via my router (NAT active on port 1883), I get the following sequence (on the server side).

server tcpdump port 1883:

```
7     2015-10-01 12:24:30.962080    192.168.1.1    192.168.1.97    TCP    121   55061→1883 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=2920 Len=67
8     2015-10-01 12:24:30.962101    192.168.1.97    192.168.1.1    TCP    54    1883→55061 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=68 Win=29200 Len=0
11    2015-10-01 12:24:30.968867    192.168.1.97    192.168.1.1    TCP    58    1883→55061 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=68 Win=29200 Len=4
12    2015-10-01 12:24:30.971556    192.168.1.1    192.168.1.97    TCP    60    55061→1883 [ACK] Seq=68 Ack=5 Win=2916 Len=0
13    2015-10-01 12:24:30.989599    192.168.1.1    192.168.1.97    TCP    92    55061→1883 [PSH, ACK] Seq=68 Ack=5 Win=2916 Len=38
14    2015-10-01 12:24:31.171216    192.168.1.97    192.168.1.1    TCP    58    [TCP Retransmission] 1883→55061 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=68 Win=29200 Len=4
15    2015-10-01 12:24:31.171411    192.168.1.1    192.168.1.97    TCP    60    [TCP Dup ACK 12#1] 55061→1883 [ACK] Seq=106 Ack=5 Win=2916 Len=0
```

Note that it happens only with the **lwip** based client; I have tested successfully using the mqtt module under node.js.

DOes anyone has an idea what what is wrong in the format of the packets sent?

Thanks, Dan.

Comment: It's possible that you're seeing bufferbloat effects. That is, the retransmit was queued to be sent before the first ACK arrived, but actually put on the wire afterwards. Counterintuitively, performance may be helped by having a smaller transmit buffer queue.

Comment: Well, that sounds interesting as the client (lwip) has a significant latency for getting/interpreting messages. But, correct me if I am wrong, as the tcpdump has been achieved on the server side, the packets present in the dump file is the image of the packets received on the interface in the same order. Packet retransmission (14) occurs 200ms after the first packet is sent (11). Even if an ACK (12) has been received during the first 2.7ms. In your opinion, what could be the conditions for ignoring an incoming packet?

Comment: I am wondering if there is a special case in terme of IP Protocol when the connection scheme is as described above: Client (subnet) -> Router -> Modem (NAT routed thanks to dyndns) -> Server